# Where I am wrong?

Tags: differential-equations, symbolic, algebraic-manipulation

I have an ODE: ( I want to write a code for Manuel solution algorithm)

[image]...**(Eq.4)**

**STEP 1:** Assume that the solution of ODE can be expressed by
[image]

```
ClearAll["Global`*"]
m = 2;
U[ξ_] = Sum[Subscript[l, i] Exp[-Φ[ξ]^i], {i, 0, m}]
auxEQ = Exp[-Φ[ξ]] + μ Exp[Φ[ξ]] + λ
```

**STEP 2:** By substituting Eq. (8) into Eq. (4) and using the auxiliary equation in Eq. (9), and then collecting all terms with the same order of $\exp(−\phi(\xi))$ together, the left hand
side of Eq. (4) is converted into a new polynomial in $\exp(−\phi(\xi))$. Setting each coefficient of this polynomial to
zero, yields a system of algebraic equations for $l_0,l_1,\ldots l_m,
\lambda$ and $\mu$.

```
 ODE = 3 U[ξ] D[U[ξ], {ξ, 2}] - 3 (D[U[ξ], ξ] )^2 + U[ξ]^3
 newODE = ODE //. {D[Φ[ξ], ξ] -> auxEQ, D[Φ[ξ], {ξ, 2}] -> D[auxEQ, ξ]}; 
 algebraicSYSTEM=CoefficientList[newODE, 
   Table[E^-n Φ[ξ], {n, 0, m}]] == 0 // LogicalExpand
```

I should get the following algebraic system:
[image]

But my *Mathematica* code gives a different result.

Comment: The command of Maple `dsolve(3*u(x)*diff(u(x), x, x) - 3*diff(u(x), x)^2 + u(x)^3 = 0)` produces $$u\! \left(x\right)=-\frac{\tanh\! \left(\frac{\left(x+\textit{_}\mathit{C2}\right) \sqrt{3}}{6 \textit{_}\mathit{C1}}\right)^{2}-1}{2 \textit{_}\mathit{C1}^{2}}  .$$

Comment: The command of Mathematica 12.3 `DSolve[3*u[x]*u''[x] - 3*u'[x]^2 + u[x]^3 == 0, u[x], x]` performs `{{u[x] -> 
   InverseFunction[-((2 ArcTan[Sqrt[-C[1] + (2 #1)/3]/Sqrt[C[
            1]]] #1 Sqrt[-3 C[1] + 2 #1])/(Sqrt[C[1]]
            Sqrt[(3 C[1] - 2 #1) #1^2])) &][x + C[2]]}, {u[x] -> 
   InverseFunction[(2 ArcTan[Sqrt[-C[1] + (2 #1)/3]/Sqrt[C[
          1]]] #1 Sqrt[-3 C[1] + 2 #1])/(Sqrt[C[1]]
          Sqrt[(3 C[1] - 2 #1) #1^2]) &][x + C[2]]}}`.

Comment: Thank you. But I want to write a code for Manuel solution algorithm.

Comment: Can you add a reference for Manuel solution algorithm to make the post more useful?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First of all, you've made 2 simple mistakes:

1. When defining `U[ξ]` you wrote `Exp[-Φ[ξ]^i]`, but it should be `Exp[-Φ[ξ]]^i`.
2. When defining `algebraicSYSTEM` you wrote `E^-n Φ[ξ]`, but it should be `Exp[-n Φ[ξ]]`.

Then, you've misunderstood the usage of `CoefficientList`, please read the document of it carefully.

A trivial issue is `newODE` can actually be defined with 1 rule. Your original attempt is not wrong, of course.

The following is the fixed code.

```
m = 2;
U[ξ_] = Sum[Subscript[l, i] Exp[-Φ[ξ]]^i, {i, 0, m}]
auxfunc[ξ_] = Exp[-Φ[ξ]] + μ Exp[Φ[ξ]] + λ

ODE = 3 U[ξ] D[U[ξ], {ξ, 2}] - 3 (D[U[ξ], ξ])^2 + U[ξ]^3;
newODE = ODE //. Derivative[i_]@Φ :> Derivative[i - 1]@auxfunc

CoefficientList[newODE, Exp[-Φ[ξ]]] == 0 // Thread // Column
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Answer (score 3):

Your definition of $u(\xi)$ does not match the book definition.  There are also problems with your usage of `CoefficientList`.  Try it like this:

```
ClearAll["Global`*"]
Clear["Derivative"]

m = 2;
u[ξ] = Sum[a[k] Exp[-k ϕ[ξ]], {k, 0, m}]
ϕ'[ξ] =  Exp[-ϕ[ξ]] + μ Exp[ϕ[ξ]] + λ
ode = 3 u[ξ] D[u[ξ], {ξ, 2}] - 3 (D[u[ξ], ξ])^2 + u[ξ]^3;

Thread[CoefficientList[ode, Exp[-ϕ[ξ]]] == 0]
```

I have used `a[k]` because $l$ looks too much like the number 1 and $i$ looks like the imaginary unit.